# Close all other command prompt windows and start a new one

Tags: batch-file

I am tryingt o create a batch file so that when I click it all of my command prompt windows close and a new one begins, however once I click it the new one does not appear.

This is my code:

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
start /MIN cmd.exe
```

I am able to launch the new command prompt window if I remove the line `taskkill /IM cmd.exe`, however of course the other windows will not close, so I think it is a problem with that line.

Comment: One trick would be to use powershell for this because it doesn't use cmd.exe. Otherwise you are killing your own current process

Comment: What about making sure that the required running instance has a unique title then closing any without that title? e.g. `TaskKill /Fi "WindowTitle NE UniqeTitle" /Im Cmd.exe /F /T`

Comment: You could add the `/F` (force) option and try again, but I guess it will also kill the task your code is running in. Anyway, just to clarify: `taskkill` does not close windows, it terminates processes (multiple `cmd` processes might share the same console window)...